# How can i filter the dictionary through values in such a way?

Tags: python

Well I want to find elements of list  -cash in option dictionary. If I get any values of option match the cash element then I want to create a dictionary where cash element becomes the key and option key becomes the values.

I tried this but it is giving an error - TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

```
first = [12, 36, 6, 84, 34, 68, 90]

second = {"one": 34, "two": 36, "three": 42, "four": 36}

new = {}

for p in first:
  for a,b in second.items():
     if p in b:
        new[p] = a
```

this is the output I wish to have

```
new = {34: "one", 36: {"two", "four"}}
```

Could you help me figuring out what mistake did I do in the above code?

Comment: If the keys in `second` are not lists then why use `in`? Instead you must use `==`.

Comment: Raj -  Do you mean "in" is only used when both are either lists or dictionary? If one is list and other is dict, "in" can't be used ?

Comment: @rohanpatni ` `b` is `int`, not a `list` or `dict`. You can't use `in` with it.

Comment: Thanks Raj, Well I tried using == and here is what I got {36: 'four', 34: 'one'}. But  I was supposed to get  {34:"one", 36:["two","four"]}.

Comment: @rohanpatni, You are not going to obtain the desired output with just `new[p] = a`. You override previous values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slightly edit your approach in this way:

```
first = [12, 36, 6, 84, 34, 68, 90]
second = {"one": 34, "two": 36, "three": 42, "four": 36}

new = {}

for key_s, s in second.items():
    if s in first:
        if s in new:
            if isinstance(new[s], str):
                new[s] = {new[s]}
            new[s].add(key_s)
        else:
            new[s] = key_s

# new = {34: "one", 36: {"two", "four"}}
```

Comment: This is nice! +1, but using `defaultdict` can reduce some `if`s.

Comment: Riccardo, thanks for the solution. Well I have just read about isinstance and I have one question.  Why are you checking if the new is a string and if it is, you are converting it to dictionary - new[s] = {new[s]}. Don't you think "new"
will always be dictionary since we created the blank dictionary as "new". Why do you think it was necessary to check if it was string or not ? Thanks

Comment: @rohanpatni Your expected result is a dictionary where some values are strings (for example: `34: "one"`) and other values are sets (for example: `36: {"two", "four"}`). What my solution does is to create a string if there is a single value, and when you need more than one the value is converted to a set. Is it more clear? Maybe you wanted all the values to be sets (for example: `34: {"one"}, 36: {"two", "four"}`)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an iteration over `first` list as you are checking the membership inside the loop.

To make it easier, you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

first = [12,36,6,84,34,68,90]
second = {"one":34 , "two" : 36, "three" : 42 , "four" : 36}

new = defaultdict(set)
values = list(second.values())
for k, v in second.items():
    if v in first:
        if values.count(v) > 1:
            new[v].add(k)
        else:
            new[v] = k

print(new)
# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {34: 'one', 36: {'two', 'four'}})
```

Comment: This does not return the desired result!! The elements of `new` are not always sets (or lists), but are sometimes single elements! Downvoting until you fix it :)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco, You're right. I was quick into an answer.